# How to install a .pkg from Java Runtime?

Tags: java, macos, bash, runtime, pkg-file

I am automating an installation of an .pkg file in Mac OS X using Java and to do it I have this command for bash console:

```
echo 'Control123' | sudo -S installer -pkg /Users/george/Downloads/MyPackage.pkg -target /
```

I am executing this command from Java Runtime:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo 'Control123' | sudo -S installer -pkg /Users/george/Downloads/MyPackage.pkg -target /");
```

but the package is not installed, if execute the command in the Bash console. it works normally.

Comment: You can only invoke native commands, not shell builtins and pipes this way.

Comment: is there another way where I can Install .pkg files from Java?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't assume that a user has root privileges, and it's probably a better idea to launch the installer so the user can authorize and update the application from there. If that makes sense, then it's possible to launch the `.pkg` this way, sudo is not required:

```
String userHome = System.getProperty( "user.home" );
String cmdString = ("open " + userHome + "/Downloads/MyPackage.pkg");
```

I'm not sure why you would need echo 'Control123', but you might need to echo that separately.